# Weird error with `tlmgr` on virtual Ubuntu machine. No idea where to start

Tags: ubuntu, tlmgr

I would like to use `tlmgr` on a Windows Subsystem for Linux virtual machine with Ubuntu installed in order to manage installation of packages on my current LaTeX installation. I have noticed that most, if not all `tlmgr` result in the following:

```
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

This includes very simple commands like `tlmgr update` and `tlmgr info`. Why does this occur and how can I fix it?